# How to view a transparent image in a non-transparent way under Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, images

When opening a transparent image in gnome image viewer, the background is shown to be check board, which makes the image difficult to see.

Is there some way to view a transparent image in a non-transparent way under Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`gthumb` displays the image on a background color that will depend on your color scheme which may be better for you.

You can also try opening the image in a web browser, firefox for example. In my case, it displays the image on a dark grey background.